# zabbix change permission scheme

Tags: permissions, zabbix, schema

I have situation something like that: In zabbix I have two maps and I am looking for a solution how to set up access to the user had the ability to watch just one map.

Please on advice it is possible ?

Regards Mick

Answer (score 0):

you have to go to go to Administration tab and there you have to check users subtab. There you can configure your group users and access to the panels.